# index of element of nested list, try and except

Tags: python, validation

Have just started programming and are now stuck on a problem.
Want to find the index of a number that a user enters in a nested list.
If it is not a number **or** if the number is not in the list, the program should continue running until a valid number is written.
Then it should return a tuple with the index.
The ONLY parameter to the function is a list of strings. My code, which generates an infinite loop.... Appreciate all the help

```
def find(mylist):

    for sub_list in mylist:

        while True:    

            try:
                num in sub_list
                num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
                
                
            
            except:
                print(f"{num} is not in the list")
                continue
            else:
                break
        return (mylist.index(sub_list), sub_list.index(num))

row, col = find([['23', '24', '25'], ['26', '27', '28'], ['29', '30']])
print(row, col)

## num is 24,  should print 0,1
## num is 44, 44 is not in the list. Enter a number
```

Comment: `num in sub_list`: `num` is undefined at that point.  Shouldn't this line be put after the next one?  Besides, even if you switch the two lines the only way an exception can be raised is if the user does not type an integer which causes `int(input...)` to raise an exception.  In other word, `num in sub_list` won't raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the task of finding the number from your input loop.  For example, have `find` simply look for a single value and `raise` if it's not found -- then call `find` in your loop with a `try/except`.

```
def find(mylist, val):
    for i, sub_list in enumerate(mylist):
        if val in sub_list:
            return i, sub_list.index(val)
    raise ValueError(f"{val} is not in the list.")


def main(mylist):
    while True:
        try:
            print(find(
                mylist,
                input("Enter a number: ")
            ))
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

print(main([['23', '24', '25'], ['26', '27', '28'], ['29', '30']]))
```

```
Enter a number: 44
44 is not in the list.
Enter a number: 24
(0, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I get the same result with only the list as parameter though? With the try expect in the function.

Comment: Make another function.  You can even have the definition of `find()` nested inside that function if you don't want it to be accessible at the top level.